# date type changed after strptime and then strftime?

Tags: python, datetime

New to Python so I have question as following. Why a is not equal to b? Thank you.

```
fundData['SigDate']
    0         31DEC2008
    1         31JAN2009
    2         28FEB2009
    3         31MAR2009
    4         30APR2009
a=fundData['SigDate']
b=fundData['SigDate'].apply(lambda x : datetime.strptime(x,'%d%b%Y').strftime('%d%b%Y'))
a==b
    0         False
    1         False
    2         False
    3         False
```

Comment: anywhite space in the original definition? that'd get parsed away by strptime and wouldn't be in the strftime output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'strptime/strftime'` transformation returns a string in *sentence case* for the month entry, so your comparison is rightly `False`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>>
>>> x = "31DEC2008"
>>> dt.strptime(x,'%d%b%Y').strftime('%d%b%Y')
'31Dec2008'
>>>
>>> '31Dec2008' == '31DEC2008'
False
```

---

You can call `upper` on the string returned in your *lambda* function to make them match:

```
>>> dt.strptime(x,'%d%b%Y').strftime('%d%b%Y').upper()
'31DEC2008'
```